# Displaying currency format in CARTO Builder scorecard widget

Tags: carto

I am creating a map in CARTO Builder and I would like to have a scorecard widget showing the average income across all points on the map. In the scorecard, I want the average to be displayed with currency format, e.g. `$1,000,000.00` instead of `1,000,000`.

From what I have gathered, the scorecard widget only takes numeric types as inputs to the operation.

I have tried:

- convert the data into string currency format
- convert the data into money data type in SQL. Although this shows up in the data window, the money column is not imported with the rest of the data layer in carto Builder, leading me to believe CartoBuilder does not
  recognize money type.

Does anyone have a work around to format the scorecard or know what data type will correctly format it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a `PREFIX` option in the Formula widget options that could do the trick:

[image: prefix]